# Cut Möbius Band

Tags: general-topology, soft-question, mobius-band

$$\text{Cut a Möbius band from its center line, and then what do we get?}$$

Someone may find it's not easy to imagine without a paper in hand. However, if we cut a square paper from center line at first, and glue it as a Möbius band, we will easily see that it is a cylinder.

We can also add the number of cut lines, like three (three points) and four (four points). Now what will Möbius band be like?

It is difficult to answer from the first method, but easy from the second. In the three case, we will find there are two disconnected bands, one is a Möbius band, other is a cylinder.

---

Actually, the two methods can be simplified as below

- First paste a paper into a Möbius band, and then cut it.
- First cut a paper into pieces, and then paste it.

So my question is

> Are the two methods or viewpoints same under the homoemorphism?

I want to find a rigorous proof. Any advice is helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The point is to define rigorously gluing and cutting. For gluing, one uses the notion of *quotient topology* $X/\sim$, for some relation $\sim$. For cutting, one can just remove a subset, for example if $X$ is the unit square $X=\{(x,y)|0\leq x,y\leq1\}$, then after cutting we can get $Y=X\setminus\{y=1/2\}$.

Examine the question using the above paragraph. You can either take quotient first and then remove a subset, or first remove a subset and then take quotient. Now it is easy to verify that with the correct notations, you get exactly the same space.

Comment: I doubt that cutting is removing a subset. When we cut a paper from its center line, the line will not be removed from two pieces.

Comment: If it makes things easier for you, you can create two separate connected components by translating the upper open half somewhere away (_open_ means that the line in question remains in the lower half). If you wish, afterwards you can add a boundary (or not) to the translated half.

Comment: Note, however, that when working with actual papers, there is no distinction between open and closed squares. In other words, the boundary, which is a crucial mathematical object, does not really exist in daily life papers. Hence it seems OK to me that there is some difference between actual papers and mathematical papers, regarding the virtual line $\{y=1/2\}$ (which again, does not exist in any actual paper).

Comment: So can I see the paste as a quotient map, and cutting as an embedding map?

Comment: Yes, cutting can be thought of as an embedding, but note that it is _not_ continuous.